# SQL Sum() returning postive and negative values

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get SUM() to return the sum of a column summing the positive and negative values in the column. Instead its currently returning one positive value and one negative value, can anyone help?

```
SELECT
  LedgerAP.Period, LedgerAP.Account, SUM(LedgerAP.Amount) Amount
FROM
  LedgerAP
WHERE
  LedgerAP.Period >= 201500 AND LedgerAP.Account = N'105.71'
GROUP BY LedgerAP.Period, LedgerAP.Account
HAVING SUM(Amount) <> 0

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  LedgerAR.Period, LedgerAR.Account, SUM(LedgerAR.Amount)
FROM
  LedgerAR
WHERE
  LedgerAR.Period >= 201500 AND LedgerAR.Account = N'105.71'
GROUP BY LedgerAR.Period, LedgerAR.Account

UNION ALL

SELECT
  LedgerEx.Period, LedgerEx.Account, SUM(LedgerEx.Amount)
FROM
  LedgerEx
WHERE
  LedgerEx.Period >= 201500 AND LedgerEx.Account = N'105.71'
GROUP BY LedgerEx.Period, LedgerEx.Account

UNION ALL

SELECT
  LedgerMisc.Period, LedgerMisc.Account, SUM(LedgerMisc.Amount)
FROM
  LedgerMisc
WHERE
  LedgerMisc.Period >= 201500 AND LedgerMisc.Account = N'105.71'
GROUP BY LedgerMisc.Period, LedgerMisc.Account
```

[image: RESULT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to re-aggregate your results:

```
with l as (
      <your query here>
     )
select  period, account, sum(amount)
from l
group by period, account;
```

You can do the same thing with a subquery instead of a CTE.